# Cannot throw objects that do not implement Throwable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware, laravel-5.5, laravel-response

I am using Laravel 5.5. There is following class

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php

with Method Name: buildException

In, Laravel 5.4, I was able to return JSON in this method like below.

```
protected function buildException($key, $maxAttempts)
{
    $retryAfter = $this->getTimeUntilNextRetry($key);
    $headers = $this->getHeaders(
        $maxAttempts,
        $this->calculateRemainingAttempts($key, $maxAttempts, $retryAfter),
        $retryAfter
    );
    return response()->json('429 Too many requests');
}
```

When I try to return JSON in above method using Laravel 5.5, it says

> Cannot throw objects that do not implement Throwable

Now sure , how could I return JSON in Laravel 5.5 for above method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you cannot do it like this now any more. You need to return exception class. But what you can do is returning some custom exception class and then in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` in `render method you can add:

```
if ($e instanceof YourCustomException) {
   return response()->json('429 Too many requests');
}
```

Of course if you really need, you can add your own implementation of `handle` method and instead of throwing exception you can return response directly in there but probably throwing custom exception and handling it in Handler class is better choice.

Comment: Can u please give more details with example about YourCustomException in both places(ThrottleRequests and Handler.php)

Comment: You can create custom class that extends `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException`, in `buildException` method throw this exception and than in Handler use `if ($e instanceof YourCustomException) {`